# If g(n) = sqrt(n)^sqrt(n), does the complexity of g(n) = O(2^n)?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, discrete-mathematics

If g(n) = sqrt(n)<sup>sqrt(n)</sup>, does the complexity of g(n) = O(2<sup>n</sup>)?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/V9bxb first is a plot of the one with sqrt and the second is a plot with 2^n

Comment: `sqrt(n)^(sqrt(n)) = n^(sqrt(n)/2)` which is upper-bounded by `2^n` because the limit `lim n->infty srqt(n)^(sqrt(n))/2^n  = 0`, meaning `2^n` grows faster than `g(n)` after a certain point `n = n_0`, thus `g(n) = O(2^n)`. To see this yourself go calcult the limit (http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+n-%3Einfty+srqt(n)%5E(sqrt(n))%2F2%5En) yourself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A useful technique when comparing two exponential functions is to get them to have the same base:

> √n<sup>√n</sup> = (2<sup>lg √n</sup>)<sup>√n</sup> = 2<sup>√n lg √n</sup>

Now you're comparing 2<sup>√n lg √n</sup> against 2<sup>n</sup>, and hopefully from that it's easy to see that the former function does not grow as rapidly as the latter, so √n<sup>√n</sup> = O(2<sup>n</sup>) is indeed true.

Comment: In case it's not clear the first equality is due to `2^lg(n) = n`, where _lg_ is the logarithm with base two. The second instead is due to a power rule of exponentials, that is in general you have `(b^n)^m = b^(n*m)`.

Answer (score 5):

The other proofs are short and nice, but here is more detailed proof going to the definitions of the big-oh notations and the computation of the needed limits.

A function `g(n)` is upper-bounded by another function `f(n)` by the big-Oh notation (`g(n) = O(f(n))`) if it holds that 
([source](http://people.csail.mit.edu/alinush/6.006-spring-2014/big-oh-with-limits.pdf))

[image: first]

Put in the functions and we must compute

[image: second]

First some algebraic massage on the `g(n)` term. By the root-identities, it holds that `sqrt(n) = n^(1/2)`. Furthermore it holds that `(x^a)^b = x^(a*b)`. With that:

[image: third]

Furthermore, `2^n` is `exp(log( 2^n ))` by the logarithmic identities, and then `log(a^b) = b*log(a)` we have `2^n = exp(log( 2^n )) = exp(n * log(2))`. The same can be applied to `n^(1/2 sqrt(n))`, it becomes `exp(log( n^(1/2 sqrt(n)) = exp(1/2*sqrt(n)*log(n))`. So now we have

[image: something]

At this point we can compare the growth of the exponents, i.e. compare

[image: something2]

That limit is 0 because `const * n` grows faster than `sqrt(n)*log(n)`. This can in turn be shown the calculating the limit explicitly. Put the 1/2 and the `log2` in the denumerator. Since `n = sqrt(n) * sqrt(n)`, we can simplify it to:

[image: some4]

This limit is indeed zero, because the squareroot grows faster than logarithm by the [Orders of common functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Orders_of_common_functions). Thus the exponent of the lower function grows faster than the exponent of the upper function. Thus `g(n) = O(2^n)` is rigorously proven by the first theorem.

Answer (score 4):

One can assume `O(log n) < O(sqrt(n))` ([Order of common functions - wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Orders_of_common_functions))

The transformation works as follows:

```
sqrt(n)^sqrt(n)                2^n              # a^b = e^(ln(a) * b)
e^(ln(sqrt(n)) * sqrt(n))      e^(ln(2) * n)    # if e^a < e^b, then a < b
ln(sqrt(n)) * sqrt(n)          ln(2) * n        # / sqrt(n)
ln(sqrt(n))                    ln(2) * sqrt(n)  # ln(a^b) = b * ln(a)
0.5 ln(n)                      ln(2) * sqrt(n)  # ln(a) / ln(b) = log(a base b)
0.5 log(n base 2)              sqrt(n)          # base and constant factor don't matter
log(n)                         sqrt(n)
```

I've omitted complexity-classes for simplicity. The above should be read bottom to top for a proper proof.